# Bulk insert and update for MySQL

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

What is the best way to insert/update bulk records in single transaction?

Does anybody have sample stored procedure for insert/update json object into mysql table?

Like JSON Object -> MySQL table?

Comment: Generate a text representation of your object (the `JSON`, actually) and insert/update it the same way you do with other string/text values.

Comment: Take a look on this website: https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2013/03/26/sql-server-json-to-table-and-table-to-json/

Comment: I Just pass the json object into stored procedures....then the input data insert/update into releavent table.....sample json format[{id:1,name:'james',type:'user'}]

Answer (score 0):

INSERT IGNORE INTO tableName(field1,field2,field3,field4) VALUES ('Field1Value1', 'Field2Value1', 'Field3Value1', 'Field4Value1'),
('Field1Value2', 'Field2Value2', 'Field3Value2', 'Field4Value2'),
..
..
..
..
,
('Field1ValueN', 'Field2ValueN', 'Field3ValueN', 'Field4ValueN')

Comment: I have tried this syntax also,,,,any other way to do?

Comment: its gonna make performance issue while inserting bulk records. you can refer following link to optimize the performance http://kvz.io/blog/2009/03/31/improve-mysql-insert-performance/